Contrast enhancing very faint extended blobs in an image
I have a series of images of the night sky and I'm looking for methods to enhance very faint structures that are barely visible. The movement of those structures is visible when you click through consecutive images but they're so faint and diffuse that it's hard to know where that feature is when you look at it.
I've included 5 images in this post; you can see the movement of white faint columnar features as you click through the images. I'm trying to find a way to bring them out, but methods like CLAHE and adaptive thresholding aren't working very well. I'm stumped and any help would be appreciated. The images (PNG, 16 bits per channel) are available at this link.
Ideally I'd like a script that detects these features so I can apply the technique to many more images that I have, but I'm willing to do it by hand if a reproducible method is found. I suspect I'll have to do it by hand because of the diffusivity of the features.
JPEG variants, only 8 bpc:
DSC04653
DSC04654
DSC04655
DSC04656
DSC04657


I didn't realize that file.io did that, thanks

you're talking about that fog thing or is that some kind of aurora? -- the rotation of the earth is observable in your image sequence. to suppress that, you'd want to align the images. OpenCV has "ECC refinement" for this. -- next I would suggest removing all the stars. a lowpass would work for that. I'd recommend median blur. -- now you're left with the "signal".

Yes, that fog thing is in fact a kind of auroral phenomenon. The problem is that you can only really see the columns in the fifth image, but if you look at the image set on a big computer screen then you can barely make out the columns throughout the entire phenomenon

I uploaded them on a new host - hopefully that remains for 6 days.

And it looks like the inline photos can't be generated because of some code format issue - why?

When I ended up changing the file hoster link, SO threw a hissy fit about how the formatting didn't adhere to some code formatting standards, so I ended up deleting the inlines because I couldn't figure out a way to get them inline. I don't mind having the images be inline.

ah yes this site has some automatisms that seem to be helpful on average, but sometimes not. if you want, I can add the inline images back, or turn them into a gif so that others can see what they're getting into before downloading the whole five uncompressed images.

I can't access any of your images.

the current filebin link works for me but I've added links to jpeg versions back in, and a little gif loop to catch people's eyes

oh right, the light pollution seems to be undesired as well, so let's subtract that. it would have been useful to have a picture of just the light pollution. the aurora is fairly low-frequency itself, so lifting it out of the pollution may be tricky. opencv's median blur is also not capable of floating point of uint16 inputs, only uint8. let's see how awful that turns out

@ChristophRackwitz here is a link of the area without the aurora (57 MB 16 bit PNG). I don't know if you need the exact coordinates of the crop. Unfortunately the sky itself is lit because of the aurora later on.

I might play with this some more tomorrow. I'm limited by OpenCV and skimage's median filters. OpenCV is fast, but only uint8 and it starts glitching somewhere k>300. skimage is slow AF, probably O(k²), but it can do floats. haven't checked if it's willing to do uint16 a little quicker. there are more shenanigans I could try, including research for other median impls, or DIY of some paper I once saw... -- the picture of the general area would not help in subtracting the light pollution. I can't even tell if any part of it overlaps with the set of five that you provided.

Yes, I understand your problem - I've been facing most of the same problems for a year now. The problem is that not only does this phenomenon separate into distinct column-like features, it moves awkwardly from the right to the left in the entire set of images, and sometimes happens to have distinct column-like features, and sometimes not. Could you give me a brief rundown on what methods you tried? I'm going to try some myself - maybe there's something that you did and I didn't.

I did the alignment but there's very little point to this. in the limit (a few hours of earth rotation), it'll just spin the entire image out of frame. -- basically trying to separate "frequency bands", lowpass/highpass. stars can be removed by median, if one needed that. the aurora could be removed from the pollution, for a "pure pollution" background to subtract, which would leave stars and aurora... but the aurora signal is somewhat faint. just *10 everything to strengthen it... and you'll see terrible banding/quantization from working with uint8.

I haven't tried a gaussian on the median results. that would smooth things a little. it still won't give me a good model of just the pollution. the aurora is large enough to be part of that, large enough to require median kernel sizes beyond 300, which OpenCV fails at. I could downsample, then median, then upsample... perhaps that'll go somewhere. -- one could fit some moderate-degree polynomial to the image, excluding manually defined aurora region, and then use that. might be worth a try.

this is what I got by 4x downsampling, then median, then back up. no treatment of the stars. https://i.sstatic.net/widVbW9Y.gif downsized to 30% to fit the file size limit

Wow - in about two hours you managed to achieve what I couldn't in almost a year of trying! I'm going to try CLAHE again - maybe that'll work, or maybe I'll remove the stars first. But this is amazing!

@ChristophRackwitz would you mind sharing your code? I just tried to do what you did with both skimage and cv2, and both of them are returning really smooth images...

well I did (input - background) * 10, where background is the median-smoothed image. more or less. I'll revisit this tomorrow

The keywords to search for are astrophotography and light pollution background correction. The simplest form of which is remove all the stars (and in this case aurora) and then fit a polynomial in altitude and azimuth to the remaining brightness. You might also need to correct for any vignetting in your lens. Various amateur astronomy magazines have regular  tutorials on how to do it. Try this for a start - many other tools available and some are free.

@ChristophRackwitz Give the median filter in DIPlib a spin. It’s very fast and works for arbitrary types, including floats. Here’s a description of the algorithm I implemented there in case you’re interested: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/1138/

apply High Exposure, low Gamma

You will get:

Then apply minimum filter, you will get:

now you can localize contrast or do what ever you like
the result of another frame:

